# Merge two images with javascript

Tags: image, merge, case

I am trying to combine two images, phone case and design and get one whole image.

The first image will be the phone case (i.e. for iphone 14) and the second will be the design (any picture no matter what), I want the design image to be cropped in the shape of the phone case and the result to be one image.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

I am not sure if that is possible but if anyone has any ideas please share it.